# Sorting contents with a PS script

Tags: powershell, scripting, intune, bitlocker

**Goal of this post**:

1. Sort Name column with csv filter -contains "-POS-"
2. Only pull back the top Bitlocker key from AzureAD and place that one key into the `bitlockerKeys` column.

This is a script from - https://gitlab.com/Lieben/assortedFunctions/blob/master/get-bitlockerEscrowStatusForAzureADDevices.ps1

This is not my script, but I need it to work like this for a project I am doing. Did I mention that I am a complete PS noob here? Take it easy on me please lol.

```
function get-bitlockerEscrowStatusForAzureADDevices{
    #Requires -Modules ImportExcel
    <#
      .SYNOPSIS
      Retrieves bitlocker key upload status for all azure ad devices
      .DESCRIPTION
      Use this report to determine which of your devices have backed up their bitlocker key to AzureAD (and find those that haven't and are at risk of data loss!).
      Report will be stored in current folder.
      .EXAMPLE
      get-bitlockerEscrowStatusForAzureADDevices
      .PARAMETER Credential
      Optional, pass a credential object to automatically sign in to Azure AD. Global Admin permissions required
      .PARAMETER showBitlockerKeysInReport
      Switch, is supplied, will show the actual recovery keys in the report. Be careful where you distribute the report to if you use this
      .PARAMETER showAllOSTypesInReport
      By default, only the Windows OS is reported on, if for some reason you like the additional information this report gives you about devices in general, you can add this switch to show all OS types
      .NOTES
      filename: get-bitlockerEscrowStatusForAzureADDevices.ps1
      author: Jos Lieben
      blog: www.lieben.nu
      created: 9/4/2019
    #>
    [cmdletbinding()]
    Param(
        $Credential,
        [Switch]$showBitlockerKeysInReport,
        [Switch]$showAllOSTypesInReport
    )

    Import-Module AzureRM.Profile
    if (Get-Module -Name "AzureADPreview" -ListAvailable) {
        Import-Module AzureADPreview
    } elseif (Get-Module -Name "AzureAD" -ListAvailable) {
        Import-Module AzureAD
    }

    if ($Credential) {
        Try {
            Connect-AzureAD -Credential $Credential -ErrorAction Stop | Out-Null
        } Catch {
            Write-Warning "Couldn't connect to Azure AD non-interactively, trying interactively."
            Connect-AzureAD -TenantId $(($Credential.UserName.Split("@"))[1]) -ErrorAction Stop | Out-Null
        }

        Try {
            Login-AzureRmAccount -Credential $Credential -ErrorAction Stop | Out-Null
        } Catch {
            Write-Warning "Couldn't connect to Azure RM non-interactively, trying interactively."
            Login-AzureRmAccount -TenantId $(($Credential.UserName.Split("@"))[1]) -ErrorAction Stop | Out-Null
        }
    } else {
        Login-AzureRmAccount -ErrorAction Stop | Out-Null
    }
    $context = Get-AzureRmContext
    $tenantId = $context.Tenant.Id
    $refreshToken = @($context.TokenCache.ReadItems() | where {$_.tenantId -eq $tenantId -and $_.ExpiresOn -gt (Get-Date)})[0].RefreshToken
    $body = "grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=$($refreshToken)&resource=74658136-14ec-4630-ad9b-26e160ff0fc6"
    $apiToken = Invoke-RestMethod "https://login.windows.net/$tenantId/oauth2/token" -Method POST -Body $body -ContentType 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    $restHeader = @{
        'Authorization' = 'Bearer ' + $apiToken.access_token
        'X-Requested-With'= 'XMLHttpRequest'
        'x-ms-client-request-id'= [guid]::NewGuid()
        'x-ms-correlation-id' = [guid]::NewGuid()
    }
    Write-Verbose "Connected, retrieving devices..."
    $restResult = Invoke-RestMethod -Method GET -UseBasicParsing -Uri "https://main.iam.ad.ext.azure.com/api/Devices?nextLink=&queryParams=%7B%22searchText%22%3A%22%22%7D&top=15" -Headers $restHeader
    $allDevices = @()
    $allDevices += $restResult.value
    while($restResult.nextLink){
        $restResult = Invoke-RestMethod -Method GET -UseBasicParsing -Uri "https://main.iam.ad.ext.azure.com/api/Devices?nextLink=$([System.Web.HttpUtility]::UrlEncode($restResult.nextLink))&queryParams=%7B%22searchText%22%3A%22%22%7D&top=15" -Headers $restHeader
        $allDevices += $restResult.value
    }

    Write-Verbose "Retrieved $($allDevices.Count) devices from AzureAD, processing information..."

    $csvEntries = @()
    foreach($device in $allDevices){
        if(!$showAllOSTypesInReport -and $device.deviceOSType -notlike "Windows*"){
            Continue
        }
        $keysKnownToAzure = $False
        $osDriveEncrypted = $False
        $lastKeyUploadDate = $Null
        if($device.deviceOSType -eq "Windows" -and $device.bitLockerKey.Count -gt 0){
            $keysKnownToAzure = $True
            $keys = $device.bitLockerKey | Sort-Object -Property creationTime -Descending
            if($keys.driveType -contains "Operating system drive"){
                $osDriveEncrypted = $True
            }
            $lastKeyUploadDate = $keys[0].creationTime
            if($showBitlockerKeysInReport){
                $bitlockerKeys = ""
                foreach($key in $device.bitlockerKey){
                    $bitlockerKeys += "$($key.creationTime)|$($key.driveType)|$($key.recoveryKey)|"
                }
            }else{
                $bitlockerKeys = "HIDDEN FROM REPORT: READ INSTRUCTIONS TO REVEAL KEYS"
            }
        }else{
            $bitlockerKeys = "NOT UPLOADED YET OR N/A"
        }

        $csvEntries += [PSCustomObject]@{"Name"=$device.displayName;"bitlockerKeys"=$bitlockerKeys}
    }
        $csvEntries | Export-Excel -workSheetName "BitlockerKeyReport" -path "C:\BitLockerKeyReport.xlsx" -ClearSheet -TableName "BitlockerKeyReport" -AutoSize -Verbose
}

get-bitlockerEscrowStatusForAzureADDevices -showBitlockerKeysInReport
```

Comment: Can you expand on "Sort Name column with csv filter -contains "-POS-""? Do you want to sort the entries by name _and_ filter out anything that doesn't contain `-POS-` in the name?

Comment: Yes, that is correct Mathias! I want to hide everything that doesn't have -POS- in the name. In that Name column. There are only two columns in the exported excel. The first column = 'Name' and the second Column = 'bitlockerKeys'

Comment: Any takers on this? I need help with this please. @MathiasR.Jessen can you still help with this?

Comment: Filtering for `-POS-` is easy, but I'm not sure what you mean by "the top Bitlocker key"?

Comment: This script grabs all the bitlocker keys from Azure some machines have multiple ones I want just the active bitlocker key from Azure AD when this pulls back and outputs the file as a csv. @MathiasR.Jessen